# OpenCV Android NDK Aborting Stop

Tags: android-studio, opencv

This is my problem

```
Executed failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessExeception: Error while executing processing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd 
> with arguments {NDK_Project_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\Users\Downloads\AndroidProject\Name\App\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\obj\NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\Users\Download\AndroidProject\Name\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\lib APP_ABI=all}
```

any body know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in my build.gradle 
 sourceSets { main { jni.srcDirs = [] }. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

New Method to include Open Cv android sdk in android project ,ndk-compile support is not available in android studio and you can not use `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true` in android studio

1. Import Open Cv Module as usual and include module as dependency in app module
2. Now copy libs folder in app>src>main>jniLibs
3. After that right click on app module and select Link C++ project with Gradle
4. Now choose ndk-build as build option
5. Now choose OpenCv.mk from Open-cv-android-sdk > sdk> native > jni
6. Enjoy. Now you can use open cv native code